# Woocommerce WorldPay payment gateway Status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, worldpay

I am using WooCommerce and WorldPay payment gateway. My client requirement to display the same order status as in the WorldPay account order status. Like when order is placed and payment is completed then status is shown AUTHORISED. My client says it should be also shown AUTHORISED in woocommerce order status. And when WorldPay order status after 15 minute to 30 minutes changed from AUTHORISED to CAPTURED, In Woocommerce it should also be changed from AUTHORISED to CAPTURED.

Is there any way to change to status as WorldPay? Please help

Answer (score 0):

WorldPay has a API where you can check the status.
https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/api#getorder

You can do this with a WordPress Cronjob and change the Woocommerce Order status very easy.

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->update_status('pending', 'order_note');
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobias 
Any sample code for complete payments?